# Smallest number such that the sum of digits and the product of digits is $2000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Find the smallest number such that the sum of the digits and the product of the digits is $2000$.

I came across the following question on the internet and I am unable to solve this.

**Which mathematical tools are used to solve such kind of questions? Can anyone please explain in detail?**

Comment: So the digits' sum is $2000$, and the digits' product is also $2000$?

Comment: Well, I would first note that $2000 = 2^4\cdot 5^3$.  Maybe you can combine some of those $2$'s into $4$'s instead if you like, maybe even an $8$ if you so wish.

Comment: I reckon your number is gonna contain lots of 1s but not any 0s. DUCY?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Probably yes

Comment: Ok, so given that there's lots of 1s, what are your next thoughts for how to arrange the 1s, 2s (or 4s or 8s), and 5s in order to make your number as small as possible?

Comment: Hint to answer Adam's question: $73>37$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Hint:** The prime factorization of $2000$ is $2^4\cdot 5^3$

> This implies that among the possible digits in our number, we could have any number of $1$'s, we must have exactly three $5$'s, and we must have either four $2$'s or two $2$'s and a $4$ or one $2$ and an $8$ or two $4$'s.

Taking note of the possibilities remaining due to the restriction on the product of the digits being what they are, we then try to use the fewest number of digits and have the smallest leading string of digits possible.

> We use a $2$ and an $8$ rather than the other options for how to distribute the factors of two as this leaves us with our factors of two only occupying two slots and leaves us with a smallest possible leading digit

Arranging the digits then our final number is:

> $\underbrace{11111\cdots 11}_{1975~\text{ones}}25558$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Not intending to confuse the OP, but this number is even smaller when read in base 9. Then if changing bases is OK, wouldn't it be a better bet to replace the 8 with 222 and read the number in base 6? (considering that the 2000 is still base 10)

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA haha, sure then, so long as we had clarified that the number $2000$ we were interested in was specifically the base $10$ interpretation.  As soon as you start changing bases though, you open up a can of worms in terms of changing how $2000$ is meant to be interpreted as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Fair enough. The remark was just for fun :) Note that the OP did not specify that the number had to be positive... (No, really, your answer is perfectly correct)

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA the OP didn't specify that the number has to be an integer either. So $1\,.\,\underbrace{1111\cdots 11}_{1974~\text{ones}}25558$ is then an improvement?